# zoom for multiple images with jacklmoore's jquery zoom

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, zooming

I am using jacklmoore's jquery zoom ([jacklmore's](http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom)) (mouseOver function)

in my view;

```
<% @pictures.each do |picture| %>
  <span class='zoom' id='ex1'>
    <img src="<%= picture.image.url(:medium) %>" data-zoom-url="<%= picture.image.url %>" />
  </span>
<% end %>
```

and in my jquery file;

```
$('.zoom img').each(function(){
      var zoom_url = $(this).attr('data-zoom-url');
      $(".zoom").zoom({url: zoom_url});
   });
```

but it doesn't work for more than one image. Does anyone know how to I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I was walking on (document) in my .js file. So it was working for one time. I edited my .js file as below;

```
$(function(){
    $('#thumbnails img').each(function() {
        var original_img_url = $(this).attr('data-zoom-url');
        $(this)
        .parent()
        .zoom({url: original_img_url});
    });
});
```